# How to pass variable to BigInteger?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, biginteger

```
int n=10;
BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("n");
System.out.println(fact);
```

I am getting an error saying that it doesnot have such constructor.Can anybody please help me in passing the variable to the BigInteger object.

Comment: Which programming language? Probably there is no constructor that takes a string?

Comment: It is java language,I think so only java supports BigInteger.

Comment: .NET also has BigInteger.

Comment: I am very sorry about it.Anyways it is java.Thanks for replying.Happy hacking.

Answer (score 3):

Given the syntax I'm guessing this is Java.

The BigInteger constructor should be given a String representing a decimal value as parameter, like "10" for exemple.

In your case the it is given the String "n", which does not represent a decimal value.

To correct your code you have multiple options, you could give the String value of your integer to the BigInteger constructor:

```
int n=10;
BigInteger fact = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n));
System.out.println(fact);
```

Or you could use the static function provided by the BigInteger class:

```
int n=10;
BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
System.out.println(fact);
```

Either way you should probably check out the BigInteger documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html